# Node.js 0.10.18 bug?

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks

I have  the  Node.js (0.10.18) the **absolutely same** big loaded application on a few hosts (Debian 6). Recently, I have noticed that, in contrast of 64-bit version, the 32-bit version has a leak - Open files descriptors (sockets) permanently growing and I have to restart the application every 24 hours. Find below the monitoring data for 32 and 64-bit node.js behavior for same application.

*for 32 bit Node*
[image: 32 bit]

*for 64-bit node*
[image: 64 bit]

Does it node.js bug? Did somebody hit this?

Simon